# Serendipity: How to search, find and match posts which contains 2 users?

Tags: support, search

I'm not very experienced with [Stackoverflow searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) and I couldn't figure this one out.

Suppose I want to find at least 1 question in which [@nicael](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16630713/25) and [@serial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16630726/274502) had some activity on. How could I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630713/is-it-true-that-in-python-you-can-import-specific-functions-from-a-module-unlike), for instance? If that's even possible!

P.S.: If you're wondering how I found it, I actually found the lowest voted question first then took 2 random names out of it. So I found nothing, I just reversed what I wanted to do.

Comment: How's your SQL? [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) can get you what you want, I think.

Comment: @AakashM if there is no other way, sounds like you've got an answer I could accept! I'll be working on it... ;-)

Comment: [That](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252926/serendipity-how-to-search-find-and-match-posts-which-contains-2-users/253247#comment11481_252926)'s not an answer. **[This](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253247/71059)** is an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The necessary [Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/189421/questions-involving-activity-from-both-of-two-given-users?userId1=2963652&userId2=2292723) is a little long, because there are essentially *four* places we need to look to find the questions that a user has had some activity on:

- questions they've posted
- the questions for answers they've posted
- questions they've had other activity on (eg edits)
- the questions for answers they've had other activity on (eg edits)

I actually initially forgot the latter two of these, which is why my first version didn't get any results for the two users you picked - the only relevant activity `nicael` had is an edit.

But it works now, and it tells us that [for those two users, the question you have found is the only one where their activity intersects](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/189421/questions-involving-activity-from-both-of-two-given-users?userId1=2963652&userId2=2292723).

Comment: Freaking awesome! I was just starting to twigle with it now, and I would not expect it would be this big! But [here, I took the liberty to also add comments to the formula](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/189449/serendipity-match-posts-which-contains-these-2-users?userId1=811&userId2=274502). ;-) Although it seems like some improvement might be done there, since it takes so long and often times out! :-(